# Kotlin interface type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a scenario in which I need to marshal an object into XML. That object can be more than one type, so I created an interface that sets that object type to a generic T.

```
interface FileMarshaller<T> {
    fun marshal(object: T): File
}
```

And I will have several implementations of this interface, one for each type of object. This is one:

```
internal class DocumentFileMarshaller : FileMarshaller<Document> {

    override fun marshal(document: Document): File {
        //some kotlin code
    }
}
```

Which is fine, does what I need. The problem is in the factory. This factory receives a parameter and decides which marshaller it should retrieve based on that parameter.

```
class FileMarshallerFactory {

    internal fun createMarshaller(fileType: FileTypes): FileMarshaller<What should I put here?> {
        when (fileType) {
            FileTypes.DOCUMENT -> {
                return DocumentFileMarshaller()
            }
            else -> throw MarshallerNotFound(MARSHALLER_NOT_FOUND)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the return type of the factory. I cannot leave it blank, I cannot put Document as it's type, because I will have more implementations. How do I handle this type parameter? Maybe there is another approach other than this factory I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `FileTypes` determines what is the resulting type and it is always related to a specific type, so it makes sense to parameterize it as well. Then it is used as the "source" of `T`:

```kotlin
class FileMarshallerFactory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    internal fun <T> createMarshaller(fileType: FileTypes<T>): FileMarshaller<T> {
        when (fileType) {
            FileTypes.DOCUMENT -> {
                return DocumentFileMarshaller() as FileMarshaller<T>
            }
            else -> throw MarshallerNotFound(MARSHALLER_NOT_FOUND)
        }
    }
}

sealed interface FileTypes<T> {
    object DOCUMENT : FileTypes<Document>
}
```

Note you can't use an enum with this approach. You need a sealed interface/class.

Also, to be honest, this code design feels a little strange to me. If there is a finite number of marshallers and the caller needs to know which exactly marshaller does it acquire, it has to know about the `Document` and `FileTypes.DOCUMENT`, then wouldn't it be easier to have separate factories for each marshaller? Either through multiple functions or entirely separate classes. Maybe this is because we don't see an entire picture, but a simplified example.

Comment: Agreed the design is strange

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the comments. I will review my design

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function's return type generic if you also include that generic type information in the function parameters.

For example this function requires type information to be passed to it so it can determine what type to return.

```
val strings: List<String> = listOf<String>()
```

The `<String>` after the function name `listOf` is the generic type information that the function requires so it knows that it should return a `List<String>`

You can write your class like this to include type information in the function call.

```
class FileMarshallerFactory {

    internal fun <T> createMarshaller(fileType: FileTypes): FileMarshaller<T> {
        when (fileType) {
            FileTypes.DOCUMENT -> {
                return DocumentFileMarshaller()
            }
            else -> throw MarshallerNotFound(MARSHALLER_NOT_FOUND)
        }
    }
}
```

to call this new function you must include type information like so:

```
val marshaller: FileMarshaller<Document> = createMarshaller<Document>(FileTypes.Document)
```

But in my opinion this is a bit redundant.

### A Better Way

Alternatively, you can also use the given type information to determine which FileMarshaller to instantiate.

```
class FileMarshallerFactory {

    internal inline fun <reified T> createMarshaller(): FileMarshaller<T> {
        when (T::class) {
            Document::class -> {
                return DocumentFileMarshaller()
            }
            else -> throw MarshallerNotFound(MARSHALLER_NOT_FOUND)
        }
    }
}
```

What we have here is an inline function with a reified type parameter. Type information is typically only available at compile-time and is not available at run-time due to something called *type erasure*. Making the function inline with reified types makes the type information available at run-time so you can use it in a `when` to decide which FileMarshaller to instantiate.

More about kotlin type erasure here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure

### Why not FileMarshaller<Any> ?

Some may say that the easiest way to solve your specific problem is to return a `FileMarshaller<Any>` and this will be valid and compilable but I disagree with this approach. While this may work it would also sacrifice type-safety because now you can call `marshall(Any)` and give it any argument.

Comment: The first way is just wrong and shouldn't even be mentioned. The `T` is decided by the caller, while the actual type of the return value is decided by the implementation. Calling `createMarshaller<Something>(FileTypes.OtherThing)` would be lying.

Comment: @Joffrey I wanted to demonstrate how one can write code so that the generic return type is based on the passed generic parameter - and then shown why you shouldn't do so. Would you prefer that I didn't illustrate that at all?

Comment: I have no problem doing this, but what you said about it is that you find it redundant, not that it's incorrect by essence. So it's still kinda presented as a valid option at the moment